# Ternary Operator help in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, ternary-operator

```
  public int getCurrentRemainingCr() {
        return (currentEarnedCr >= 120)?(REQUIRED_CR - currentEarnedCr):0;
```

I'm trying to use ternary operators in place of if-else...basically my if-else was implying that if current credit is greater than or equal to 120, then set cred remaining to 0. This above code though still brings up issue in test method in junit.

Comment: Dont understand why people are giving downvotes without any comments?

Comment: @MartinFrank what do you mean here?

Comment: Probably because you're implying your method isn't working, then you show us some tests that don't call that method, and call other methods that we can't see.  It appears that some people have figured out what you're trying to do anyway.  But were it not for that, we would have not have nearly enough information to help you.  Please read about [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Exmaples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: well you were faster @ajb - your question is missing the problem description! you say your unit test fails - but how does it fail? can you provide further information on that?

Comment: just showed the class and test class in junit, sorry about the lack of info in beginning

Comment: Please do _not_ edit questions in such a way as to make them totally different questions, especially after they've been answered. It invalidates the entire concept of SO. If you have a new question, ask it as a new question. There's no limit or quota involved :-)

Answer (score 5):

You have your true/false results the wrong way around.

The ternary operator is:

```
(something) = (condition) ? (value if true) : (value if false);
```

Hence "if current credit is greater than or equal to 120, then set cred remaining to 0" would be done as:

```
return (currentEarnedCr >= 120) ? 0 : (REQUIRED_CR - currentEarnedCr);
```

Comment: thank you, i did that but i'm still getting 2 failures when using junit to test methods in a test class. i posted update

Comment: @gerryluci, since it's a different question, you should post it as a different question. This one will most likely be closed a a simple typographical error anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the order

Change

```
return (currentEarnedCr >= 120)?(REQUIRED_CR - currentEarnedCr):0;
```

To

```
return (currentEarnedCr >= 120)?0:(REQUIRED_CR - currentEarnedCr);
```

Why?

In `Ternary Operator`

```
 result = someCondition ? value1 : value2;
```

if `someCondition` is `true` `result` become `value1` else `result` become `value2`